# Jmeter regex variable number of lines

Tags: regex, xpath, jmeter

My question is, how can a Jmeter regular expression be written so that it does not matter how many lines are in the parsed text? For example, the Regular Expression:

```
<FMSFlightPlan>\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)</FMSFlightPlan>
```

will match the 7 line string shown below and return everything between the two  tags

```
<FMSFlightPlan>
8725
AN NTEST/GL 
- FPN/FN/RP:DA:GCRR:AA:LEMD:F:KORAL,N29439W012347.UG5. 
SONSO,N30007W012061.UN871.VJF,N36144W005585.UN10. 
HIJ,N38305W005060.Z230.SOTUK,N39116W004448 
</FMSFlightPlan>
```

However, the same regular expression will return an NA for the following 6 line string:

```
<FMSFlightPlan>
C90D
AN N9696T/GL 
- FPN/FN/RP:DA:KDEN:AA:KSFO:F:DBL,N39264W106537.J80. 
ILC,N38150W114237..RUMPS,N38072W117163..OAL,N38002W117462 
</FMSFlightPlan>
```

I understand that Template must be set for the correct number of lines as well, I don't believe this is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to establish dotall mode, which basically tells the regular expression extractor to parse new lines as if they were whitespace. dotall mode is established by adding the tag (?s) to the very beginning of the regular expression like so:

```
(?s)<FMSFlightPlan>(.*?)</FMSFlightPlan>
```

However... I still haven't been able to print the matched text. For some reason the Beanshell Assertion I'm using doesn't recognize the regular expression Reference Name as a variable and gives me the error message:

> Assertion error: true
>       Assertion failure: false
>       Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*;  //write out the data results to a file outfile = "/Users/Dani . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 12, column 380.  Encountered: "\n" (10), after : "\"3811\tYes\tAAR\tSTN\t835\t\t$B738\tfp,nradps,art,CCAAN,EXCD,wp00,p00\t37919\ta0\ti\t10\t0\t3\t0\t \t14\t 25/M\t0000ADF\t140785\t133806\t006979\t01:15:00\t0484\t360\t0379\t360\t0112\t 000932\tP00 \t007115\t2013-02-13T21:23:00Z\t2013-02-14T08:35:00+00:00\t000837\t00:10:00\t000000\t00:00:00\t000837\t00:10:00\t000000\t000000\t000000\t00:00:00\t000000\t00:00:00\t"

I'm currently attempting to use a User Defined Variable to ensure the regular expression is recognized by the Beanshell Assertion.

Thanks to everyone for your responses!