# Beanshell error message with

Tags: regex, jmeter, beanshell

I've been trying to use a the following regular expression extractor

```
Reference Name: FMSFlightPlan
Regular Expression: (?s)<FMSFlightPlan>(.*?)</FMSFlightPlan>
Template: $1$
Match No. 1
```

to match the string between the two FMSFlightPlan tags in the XML (the number of lines between the tags varies, hence the `(?s)` establishing dotall mode)

```
<FMSFlightPlan>
6500
AN NTEST/GL 
- FPN/FN/RP:DA:LEMG:AA:LEXJ:F:BLN,N38092W003375.UN865. 
BUGIX,N42215W003381.R753.EMANU,N42575W003469 
 </FMSFlightPlan>
```

Several testing applications tell me that my regex is correct. However when I try to use a Beanshell Assertion to print out the captured string I get the error message:

> Assertion error: true
>       Assertion failure: false
>       Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*;  //write out the data results to a file outfile = "/Users/Dani . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 12, column 380.  Encountered: "\n" (10), after : "\"3811\tYes\tAAR\tSTN\t835\t\t$B738\tfp,nradps,art,CCAAN,EXCD,wp00,p00\t37919\ta0\ti\t10\t0\t3\t0\t \t14\t 25/M\t0000ADF\t140785\t133806\t006979\t01:15:00\t0484\t360\t0379\t360\t0112\t 000932\tP00 \t007115\t2013-02-13T21:23:00Z\t2013-02-14T08:35:00+00:00\t000837\t00:10:00\t000000\t00:00:00\t000837\t00:10:00\t000000\t000000\t000000\t00:00:00\t000000\t00:00:00\t"

So it seems the extractor returns a string but the Beanshell Assertion doesn't recognize it as a variable. Why would this be the case after establishing dotall mode? Is there an escaping error somewhere? I also don't understand what the error message means by

```
Encountered: "\n"
```

since there are no \n characters in the text being parsed.

I've considered using XPath extractor instead of Regular Expression extractors but have heard that this is not optimal when a lot of operations or threads are involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jmeter regex variable number of lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165239/jmeter-regex-variable-number-of-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(?s) - means Single line, correct?  It is then hitting a \n which is a new line signal.  That is probably causing the error.  It is not expecting a new line character.

Could you use the regular Response Assertion?  I think you can use the regex in the Patterns to test.

Comment: Right, (?s) means single line. But where is it hitting a new line signal in the parsed text? I don't see anything in the text block and there aren't any \n signals in the Beanshell assertion, though I don't think that would matter.